# Angular 2/4 get photo from computer and display photo

Tags: html, angular

how can I get photo from computer and display photo on html page?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but below plugins can be useful for you

[webcam-directive](http://jonashartmann.github.io/webcam-directive/#/)

[ng-camera](https://github.com/bcabanes/ng-camera)